# Java Applet removing all content from HTML page

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I have the following Java Applet, which makes a simple sound:

```
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Sound extends Applet { 
    AudioClip soundFile1; 

    public void init() {             
        soundFile1 = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"collectgarments_alreadyassigned.wav"); 
        soundFile1.play(); 
    }
}
```

I want to use this applet in an HTML page, which is inside a .net project. I want it to be deployed eg make its sound onClick, so am trying to create a JavaScript method to play the sound.

So far I have the following:

```
function Sound() {
    var attributes = { id:'SoundApplet', code:'Sound.class', archive:'Java/Sound.jar', width:0, height:0} ;
    var parameters = { permissions:'sandbox'} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
}
```

This method makes the sound, but it also makes all the HTML disappear on the screen.

Possible reasons for this I can think of are that the Applet is trying to rewrite all the HTML on the page but is not being given any HTML to write?

If so a possible solution could be to include it in a div in a similar way to a div set to `display="none"', but I would not know how to do that as this is a sound not a visual aspect.

Maybe my thoughts are completely wrong and it is something else altogether.

I cannot find anything relevant on the internet and the internet explorer debugger is no help either.

Anyone else come across this problem??

Comment: FYI HTML5 can play audio all by itself.  You should probably show the html/js invocation as well.

Comment: @AlexK. I know, but this is an old application and on the client machines it is not playing the sound hence the need to implement a java applet

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. I do not know the reasons that this works, but it does:

```
function Sound()
    {
        var app = document.createElement('applet');
        app.id= 'SoundApplet';
        app.archive= 'Java/Sound.jar';
        app.code= 'Sound.class';
        app.width = '0';
        app.height = '0';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(app);
    }
```